# Check disk usage in Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04

I am new in Ubuntu so I do not really know much about it.
I wonder if there is any way to check the disk usage of the HDD by the processes, not by the usage. I mean like it is in windows when you open task manager and it shows you in percentage the use.

[image: I mean like in that photo]

Thanks in advance!
Toni

P.S.:I use Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: That image a cpu usage by process. Do you want to have that or to have disk usage? There is a mismatch between your question and the image.

Comment: Oops, sorry.I mean disk usage by process.I will correct that.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use the software called "**System Monitor**" to find such information.

Comment: Yes, system monitor! There is IOTOP too - http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/ , https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=iotop